# How to convert "\003" to int in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, int

How to convert "\003" to int in C? I have following code.

```
void* message="\003";
char* bptr;
printf("%ld",strtol((char*)message,&bptr,10));
```

It is showing 0 as output.

Comment: `strtol()` is for converting the text representation of a number to a `long`. Since `'\003' isn't a digit, what were you expecting this to give?

Comment: Also, `strtol` returns a result of type `long`; `"%d"` requires an argument of type `int`. Since `printf` is variadic, there is no implicit conversion. Either use `"%ld"` or cast the `strtol()` call to `int`.

Comment: Maybe the OP is not aware that the string is not literally what it appears to be. The backslash followed by three digits means an octal character code.

Comment: @FredLarson: I would have thought the `\0` was a `null terminator`

Comment: @Andrew: No, the `\003` is a 3-digit octal escape representing the character with value `3`.

Comment: @sattu: Please explain in more general terms how you want to map strings to integers. For example, how would you represent the integer value `1000`? And why is `message` defined as `void*` rather than `char*`?

Comment: I'm downvoting your question because, as it stands, it's incomplete and unlikely to be useful to future readers.

Comment: hmm..i think so. . Maybe some time later I will be able to explain more clearly. Thank you though :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string literal `"\003"` specifies a string consisting of two characters; the first has the value 3, and the second is the implicit `'\0'` null character terminator.

The character with the value 3 is typically not a printable character. In particular, it's not the digit `'3'`.

If you want to extract the `int` value `3` from that string, you can do it like this:

```
int result = ((char*)message)[0];
```

But that doesn't seem like a particularly useful thing to do.

I have to wonder (1) why you declared `message` as `void*` rather than as `char*`, and (2) why you're using a string containing the control character `'\003'` to represent the integer value `3`.

The usual way to represent an integer value as a string represents the integer `3` as `"3"`, not as `'\003'`.  You can certainly represent (small) integer values as single bytes, but that would generally use a single `char` or `unsigned char` object, not a string or array.  Finally, there are ways to represent arbitrary numbers as sequences of bytes, but if you're doing that you haven't told us the details of your representation; for example, what string would represent the integer value `1000`?

Comment: ya. you are correct. I represent arbitrary numbers as sequence of bytes. 123456789 is repesented as "\025\315[\a". Using void* does not serve any special purpose.

Comment: @sattu: Please update your question to explain the representation you're using. I don't see how `"\025\315[\a"` maps to `123456789`; I could probably figure it out if I took the time, but I'm not going to, and you can't expect any future readers to do so.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Those are the ASCII characters for the little-endian binary of 123456879.